# How do I fix printing from El Capitan to shared Windows printer?

Tags: network, windows, printing, smb

We have a small network that consists of 3 workstations:

1. Windows 8.1 Pro 32 bit PC with Canon LBP 6020 printer connected to USB and shared to network.
2. Windows 7 Pro SP1 32 bit notebook.
3. MacBook with macOS 10.11 El Capitan installed.

2 and 3 use the shared Canon printer connected to 1. Though, MacBook (3) is unable to print after the update to macOS 10.11. The print task freezes in queue with "Sending print data" status. On the Windows 8.1 PC we also have a task in queue freezed with "Putting in queue" (it's the translation) status with size of 62 bytes.

What I've tried already:

1. Disabling antivirus and firewall on Windows 8.1 PC.
2. Updating Canon driver on macOS to 3.87.
3. Resetting print system on macOS.
4. Adding the printer manually using the smb://user:pass@ip/LBP6020 URI.
5. Adding the printer manually using the lpd://ip/LBP6020 URI - from the "Printers & Scanners" and from CUPS web-interface - the result is the same and it's weird: the URI automatically changes to cnbma://localhost:59687 and obviously doesn't print to LPD.
6. Connecting the printer to MacBook directly by USB - it works like a charm out of the box, but MacBook is not always in the office, so Windows 8.1 PC should be the print server.

Please help me fix this issue so it will be possible to print from MacBook again.

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct for Windows printer sharing? I know the URL syntax for ipp when using OS X printer sharing is:

    `ipp://printserver.example.com/printers/Printer_Name`

Note the /printers in the URL.

Comment: @MacManager, I'm not sure because it's not documented anywhere, but according to different HOW-TO's, the URI's I used were right.

Comment: Drat- it was a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this worked pretty much: http://tweaks.com/windows/46495/enable-ios-airprint-support-on-windows/

15 minutes to set up and test.